# How does the counters work when a class is referenced by another class and with getters

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

## Problem description

I am trying to understand how the  `shared_ptr`  counters work. In my class  `A`  when I  used a getter the counter incremented by 1. When used an instance of  `A` in class `B` the counter incremented by 2. When I got Done with class  `B` the destructor of  `A` got called twice.

What I didn't understand and what confused me is the following:

- Why did the counter of `A` increment by 1 when we called the getter `a.a()`. Is it because we returned a pointer by Copy so now we have 2 pointers right?
- Why do we have a counter of 3 when the desctructor of `A` was called?
- In class `B` why did the counter increment by 2?
- After finishing of class `B` how was the destructor of `A` called?
- When I use `reset` in the both destructors it gets weirder.

---

## Source Code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class A {
        public:
        A(int a):_a( make_shared<int>(a)) {cout <<"A constructor" << endl;}
        ~A(){/*_a.reset();*/cout <<"After destructor, number of As "<< _a.use_count() <<endl;}
        std::shared_ptr<int> a(){return _a;}
        //private:
         std::shared_ptr<int> _a;
    };
    
    class B {
        public:
        B(A a):_b( make_shared<A>(a)) {cout <<"B constructor" << endl;}
        ~B(){ /*_b.reset();*/ cout <<"After destructor, number of Bs "<< _b.use_count() << endl;}
         std::shared_ptr<A> b(){return _b;}
        private:
          std::shared_ptr<A> _b;
    };
    
    
    
    int main()
    {  
        int number = 10;
        A a(number);
        cout <<"counter of A is " << a._a.use_count() << endl;
        cout <<"counter of A is " << a.a().use_count() << endl;
        
        B b(a);
        cout <<"counter of A is " << a.a().use_count() << endl;
        cout <<"counter of B is " << b.b().use_count() << endl;
        
        return 0;
}

  A--->Number: Counter = 1
  B(constructor) pass A by value : counter = 2
  B--->Number: Counter = 3
```

---

## Output without reset

A constructor
counter of A is 1
counter of A is 2
B constructor
After destructor, number of As 3
counter of A is 3
counter of B is 2
After destructor, number of Bs 1
After destructor, number of As 2
After destructor, number of As 1

## Output with reset

A constructor
counter of A is 1
counter of A is 2
B constructor
After destructor, number of As 0
counter of A is 3
counter of B is 2
After destructor, number of As 0
After destructor, number of Bs 0
After destructor, number of As 0

Comment: `reset` makes your pointer empty. Calling `use_count` on an empty pointer will always give you 0.

Comment: @r3musn0x ok it becomes 0. then inside B we have new A Then pass by value then B pointing to A. So back to 3. is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A quick answer

- Everytime you call `a.a()` it returns a new shared pointer to the resources. The first one is the member variable. They are eventually released but there's no quarantees as you don't store the returned shared pointer into a variable (which would bind it to a scope).
- The first `After destructor, ...` is because you copy value of `A a` into constructor of B. If you wish to avoid copy, then use a reference `B(A& a)`.
- The number 3 is because of three shared_pointers, the `A a` internal one, the returned but not released `a.a()` result AND the copy of `A a` passed to the constructor of `B`.
- In class B you also return new shared pointer in `b.b()` -> increment counter by one.

I hope this covers all of your questions, I can try to clarify further if you have  any questions.

Comment: Holy Moly It got weird. I Added a cout in the constructors and I got the destructor of A to be called after the constructor of B. Please check it

Comment: That was already in your original code. If you change B constructor from `B(A a)` to `B(A& a)` it will disappear (no more copy value).